# How to print full schema with Django?

Tags: django

I am moving my Django app to an offsite MySQL server, but the app will live on a different machine.

Is there a command to run that will print the schema for my app so I can just easily get started on the new machine? Or does it not work like that?

While writing this it occured to me -- is the easiest thing to put the MySQL credentials in the Django settings, and use sync.db?

Answer (score 0):

The best method to migrate your schema is by using [South Migrations](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Read through the first part of the very simple tutorial and see how it works: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [sqlall](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname) command, which will print out the database commands you will need to run to create your schema on the database server.

Alternately, if your settings.py is already pointed at the new database - you should just be able to run syncdb and have everything get created that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit on it.  use `dumpdata` to dump the data on your app machine, wire up your settings file to connect to your new DB, then `syncdb` and `loaddata`.

Comment: dumpdata dumps more than just the schema. I assume the OP doesn't need the data on his dev machine, only the schema.

Comment: then, yes, syncdb is enough.